# Laravel Spatie Roles & Permissions: How to change default tables?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-permission

I am using Laravel Spatie Roles & Permissions and wish to change the default roles and permissions tables which power it.

I am changing the `table_names` values in:
 `<laravel_project>\vendor\spatie\laravel-permission\config\permission.php`

The new tables have identical columns and datatypes to the existing columns.

I then run `php artisan permission:cache-reset` and try to make a change to an existing role or permission but the old table is still being updated and not the new ones as specified in this config file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never change in the vendor file because it will not save the changes whenever you use `composer update`. Instead you can override the default changes in the config files like:

[Publishing the vendor files](http://php%20artisan%20vendor:publish%20--provider=%22Spatie%5CPermission%5CPermissionServiceProvider%22) using the command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider"
```

And extending into whatever you wish to [Changing into desired Model and Table Name](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/advanced-usage/extending/)

Comment: Thanks, I should have been editing ```config\permission.php```